# CouchDB document size limits

Tags: couchdb

I'm tidying up the security in my app a little bit, and I have a quick question.

I looked through my couchdb configuration and I noticed a maximum document size of 4294967296. Is that 4 MBs? And might you be able to put that in human terms, like a 100,000 line JSON doc? More? less?

Answer (score 7):

That's 4 GIGAbytes.

So, that's a DVD.

Comment: Thanks, Will! So if someone comes along one of my forms and decides they want to upload a bunch of 'dvds' to my Couch, just to mess up my data, how might I stop that? Like if someone's attack just consists of uploading massive amounts of data.

Comment: @Costa You might restrict the size of an allowed upload to what fits your needs. The DB is only one part of your application that you are controlling and thus are responsible for.